# Creating Dynamic Thresholds In My Application

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an application where there are "Master Run Conditions" and users enter data each time they work on a certain job or task. I want to create thresholds so we can see data outside of our tolerance or master conditions. Usually, I would create a table where thresholds can be defined as +-X%, then hard code the comparison statements. I don't want to hard code. I want the thresholds to be dynamic.

I have three tables. Here is some example code to recreate those:

```
CREATE TABLE M_CONDITIONS --What the master conditions for an item should be
( 
    ITEM VARCHAR2(30) PRIMARY KEY,
    RUN_RATE NUMBER,
    THICKNESS NUMBER,
    TEMPERATURE NUMBER,
    TENSION NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE R_DATA --Run data collected by employees
( 
    JOB_NO NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    ITEM VARCHAR2(30),
    RUN_RATE NUMBER,
    THICKNESS NUMBER,
    TEMPERATURE NUMBER,
    TENSION NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE M_THRESH ( --thresholds (%) used to compare run data to master conditions and flag large variances
    THRESH_NAME VARCHAR2(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    BELOW_MIN NUMBER,
    BELOW_MAX NUMBER,
    ABOVE_MIN NUMBER,
    ABOVE_MAX NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO M_CONDITIONS values ('ITEM-ABC', 500, 30, 20, 20);
INSERT INTO M_CONDITIONS values ('ITEM-DEF', 550, 40, 10, 15);
INSERT INTO M_CONDITIONS values ('ITEM-HIJ', 400, 60, 20, 30);

INSERT into R_DATA values (10000, 'ITEM-ABC', 525, 29, 21, 22);
INSERT into R_DATA values (10001, 'ITEM-ABC', 553, 32, 18, 20);
INSERT into R_DATA values (10002, 'ITEM-DEF', 612, 32, 12, 20);
INSERT into R_DATA values (10003, 'ITEM-HIJ', 420, 57, 12, 18);
INSERT into R_DATA values (10004, 'ITEM-HIJ', 415, 52, 22, 22);
INSERT into R_DATA values (10005, 'ITEM-HIJ', 485, 38, 16, 25);

INSERT INTO M_THRESH values ('RUN_RATE', 10, 20, 10, 20);
INSERT INTO M_THRESH values ('THICKNESS', 10, 20, 10, 20);
INSERT INTO M_THRESH values ('TEMPERATURE', 10, 20, 10, 20);
INSERT INTO M_THRESH values ('TENSION', 10, 20, 10, 20);
```

One way I thought to do this was using PIVOT. Here is the code:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT MC.ITEM, /*MC.RUN_RATE, MC.THICKNESS, MC.TEMPERATURE, MC.TENSION,*/ THRESH_NAME, THRESH_NAME AS THRESH_COL,
CASE WHEN THRESH_NAME = 'RUN_RATE' AND (MC.RUN_RATE*(1+(ABOVE_MIN/100)) <= R_DATA.RUN_RATE OR MC.RUN_RATE/(1+(BELOW_MIN/100)) >= R_DATA.RUN_RATE) THEN 1
     WHEN THRESH_NAME = 'RUN_RATE' AND (MC.RUN_RATE*(1+(ABOVE_MAX/100)) <= R_DATA.RUN_RATE OR MC.RUN_RATE/(1+(BELOW_MAX/100)) >= R_DATA.RUN_RATE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END RUN_THRESH,
CASE WHEN THRESH_NAME = 'TEMPERATURE' AND (MC.TEMPERATURE*(1+(ABOVE_MIN/100)) <= R_DATA.TEMPERATURE OR MC.TEMPERATURE/(1+(BELOW_MIN/100)) >= R_DATA.TEMPERATURE) THEN 1
     WHEN THRESH_NAME = 'TEMPERATURE' AND (MC.TEMPERATURE*(1+(ABOVE_MAX/100)) <= R_DATA.TEMPERATURE OR MC.TEMPERATURE/(1+(BELOW_MAX/100)) >= R_DATA.TEMPERATURE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END TEMP_THRESH,
CASE WHEN THRESH_NAME = 'THICKNESS' AND (MC.THICKNESS*(1+(ABOVE_MIN/100)) <= R_DATA.THICKNESS OR MC.THICKNESS/(1+(BELOW_MIN/100)) >= R_DATA.THICKNESS) THEN 1
     WHEN THRESH_NAME = 'THICKNESS' AND (MC.THICKNESS*(1+(ABOVE_MAX/100)) <= R_DATA.THICKNESS OR MC.THICKNESS/(1+(BELOW_MAX/100)) >= R_DATA.THICKNESS) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END THICK_THRESH,
CASE WHEN THRESH_NAME = 'TENSION' AND (MC.TENSION*(1+(ABOVE_MIN/100)) <= R_DATA.TENSION OR MC.TENSION/(1+(BELOW_MIN/100)) >= R_DATA.TENSION) THEN 1
     WHEN THRESH_NAME = 'TENSION' AND (MC.TENSION*(1+(ABOVE_MAX/100)) <= R_DATA.TENSION OR MC.TENSION/(1+(BELOW_MAX/100)) >= R_DATA.TENSION) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END TEN_THRESH

FROM M_CONDITIONS MC, R_DATA, M_THRESH
WHERE MC.ITEM = R_DATA.ITEM
AND MC.ITEM = 'ITEM-ABC'
)
PIVOT
(
MAX(THRESH_NAME)
FOR THRESH_COL IN ('RUN_RATE' AS RUN_RATE, 'THICKNESS' AS THICKNESS, 'TEMPERATURE' AS TEMPERATURE, 'TENSION' AS TENSION)
)
```

The issue is that I have to hard code all the comparisons in CASE statements. The output looks like this:

| ITEM | RUN_THRESH | TEMP_THRESH | THICK_THRESH | TEN_THRESH | RUN_RATE | THICKNESS | TEMPERATURE | TENSION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITEM-ABC | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |  |  | TENSION |
| ITEM-ABC | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |  | TEMPERATURE |  |
| ITEM-ABC | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | RUN_RATE |  |  |  |
| ITEM-ABC | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | RUN_RATE | THICKNESS | TEMPERATURE | TENSION |

The output I want is as follows. I want it to take THRESH_NAME from the threshold table, use that as the column header, then calculate whether its outside the tolerance or not.

BEFORE PIVOT:

| ITEM | THRESH_NAME | CALCULATION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ITEM-ABC | RUN_RATE | 1 |
| ITEM-ABC | THICKNESS | 0 |
| ITEM-ABC | TEMPERATURE | 1 |
| ITEM-ABC | TENSION | 0 |

AFTER PIVOT:

| ITEM_CODE | RUN_RATE | TENTION | TEMPERATURE | THICKNESS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TESTITEM-123456 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: This makes me think of dynamic SQL. Like the select statement is to be composed dynamically and open cursor for that SQL thus composed. Still, not having the DDL for those tables, I can't produce any code. Maybe different data structures could help you to avoid the usage of dynamic SQL

Comment: Okay I changed the example and added code to recreate a dataset to test on. Hopefully the question is clearer now.